# R data.table: Count number of match for multiple strings for two group between two DT

Tags: r, performance, sum, data.table, match

I am trying to do a rolling sum of match by working with two tables: 
**DT1**:

| M | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M01 | A | G |
| M02 | G | A |
| M03 | T | C |
| Mnn | A | G |

**DT2**:

| IND | Group | M01 | M02 | Mnn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | 1 | A | G | G |
| I2 | 1 | A | G | G |
| I3 | 1 | G | A | A |
| I4 | 2 | G | A | G |
| In | 2 | G | A | G |

I being the n individual of the group 1 or 2 and with its information about n Markers.

The **output** is the sum of both Alleles for both group and for every n Markers.

```
##Code for replicability
#DT1
DT1<-data.table(M=c("M01","M02","M03","Mnn"),
                A1= c("A","G","T","A"),
                A2=c("G","A","C","G"))
#DT2
DT2<-data.table(IND=c("I1","I2","I3","I4","In"),
                Group=c(1,1,1,2,2),
                M01=c("A","A","A","G","G"),
                M02=c("G","G","A","G","G"),
                M03=c("C","C","C","T","C"),
                Mnn=c("G","A","A","G","A"))
#M being the nn marker with its Allele1 and Allele2  

#What I did found so far: 

for (i in colnames(DT2)){
  print(i)
  DT1$A1G1[DT1$M==i]<-  sum(DT2[[i]][DT2$Group==1] == DT1$A1[DT1$M==i])    
  DT1$A2G1[DT1$M==i]<-  sum(DT2[[i]][DT2$Group==1] == DT1$A2[DT1$M==i])    
  DT1$A1G2[DT1$M==i]<-  sum(DT2[[i]][DT2$Group==2] == DT1$A1[DT1$M==i])    
  DT1$A2G2[DT1$M==i]<-  sum(DT2[[i]][DT2$Group==2] == DT1$A2[DT1$M==i]) 
}

#The output I want would be the sum of both A for the two group and for every Mnn.

#     M A1 A2 A1G1 A2G1 A1G2 A2G2
#1: M01  A  G    3    0    0    2
#2: M02  G  A    2    1    2    0
#3: M03  T  C    0    3    1    1
#4: Mnn  A  G    2    1    1    1
```

**It does the job but I feel like data.table could do it in one line and with less computation time by avoiding looping as Mnn is up to 50k and In is up to 15k it takes a long time.**

Anyone with solution would greatly help me as I have trouble working with data.table logic of key and indexes when working with two different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could make the loop a bit more efficient by using `colSums`.  Also, reduce the number of `==` by `split`ting the 'DT2' by 'Group'

```
mcols <- grep("^M", names(DT2), value = TRUE)
lst1 <- split(DT2[, ..mcols], DT2$Group)
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) {
      tmp <- lst1[[i]]
      DT1[, paste0("A1G", i) := colSums(tmp == A1[col(tmp)],  na.rm = TRUE)]
       DT1[, paste0("A2G", i) := colSums(tmp == A2[col(tmp)],  na.rm = TRUE)][]

}
```

-output

```
> DT1
        M     A1     A2  A1G1  A2G1  A1G2  A2G2
   <char> <char> <char> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:    M01      A      G     3     0     0     2
2:    M02      G      A     2     1     2     0
3:    M03      T      C     0     3     1     1
4:    Mnn      A      G     2     1     1     1
```

---

#### Benchmarks

On a slightly bigger dataset, checked the timings with OP's method and this

```
# data
set.seed(24)
DT1test<-data.table(M=sprintf('M%02d', 1:5000),
                A1= sample(c("A","G","T","C"), 5000, replace = TRUE),
                A2=sample(c("G","A","T","C"), 5000, replace = TRUE))

DT1testold <- copy(DT1test)
set.seed(42)
m1 <- matrix(sample(c("A", "G", "T", "C"), 5000 * 15000, 
    replace = TRUE), ncol = 5000, dimnames = list(NULL, DT1test$M))
DT2test<-data.table(IND=paste0("I", 1:15000),
                            Group=rep(1:300, each = 50))    
DT2test <- cbind(DT2test, m1)
```

timings - old method

```
system.time({
for (i in colnames(DT2test)){
   for(j in unique(DT2test$Group)) {
   
     DT1testold[[paste0("A1G", j)]][DT1testold$M==i] <- 
     sum(DT2testold[[i]][DT2test$Group==j] == DT1testold$A1[DT1test$M==i])
      DT1testold[[paste0("A2G", j)]][DT1testold$M==i] <- 
    sum(DT2test[[i]][DT2test$Group==j] == DT1testold$A1[DT1test$M==i])  
   
  }
  }
  
  
  
  })
   user  system elapsed 
502.603 106.631 610.908
```

timings-new method

```
system.time({
 mcols <- grep("^M", names(DT2test), value = TRUE)
 lst1 <- split(DT2test[, ..mcols], DT2test$Group)
 for(i in seq_along(lst1)) {
       tmp <- lst1[[i]]
       DT1test[, paste0("A1G", i) := colSums(tmp == A1[col(tmp)], 
        na.rm = TRUE)]
        DT1test[, paste0("A2G", i) := colSums(tmp == A2[col(tmp)], 
       na.rm = TRUE)][]

 }
 
 
 
 })
 #user  system elapsed 
 #36.079   0.968  36.934
```

Comment: Dear akrun, this is a nice solution as it works faster and does the trick. I will put this as a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you melt your two tables, and do a join on `M` and `value`, you can count by group, allele, and marker:

1. pivot these tables long, and join

```
DT_long = melt(DT2,id = c("IND", "Group"),variable.name = "M")[melt(DT1, id="M",variable.name="allele"), on=.(M,value)]
```

2. join `DT1` back on to a wide version of the sum over allele, group, and marker

```
DT1[dcast(
  DT_long[,.N, .(col =paste0(allele,"G",Group),M)],
  M~col,value.var="N",fill=0
), on="M"]
```

Output:

```
     M A1 A2 A1G1 A1G2 A2G1 A2G2
1: M01  A  G    3    0    0    2
2: M02  G  A    2    2    1    0
3: M03  T  C    0    1    3    1
4: Mnn  A  G    2    1    1    1
```

### Update:

I still find the `melt` - `dcast` solution to be faster than the looping approaches. Here is an option, that does the dcast separately for each "A" column using a helper function:

```
DT2_long <- melt(DT2,id = c("IND", "Group"),variable.name = "M")[, .N, .(Group,M, value)]
f <- function(ma, allele) {
  dcast(DT2_long[ma, on=.(M,value)][,col:=paste0(allele, "G",Group)],M~col,value.var="N")
}
do.call(cbind, lapply(c("A1", "A2"), \(a) f(DT1[, .(M, value=get(a))], a)))
```

Comment: Dear langtang, I tried your code and the DT_long was of 32 millions lines which did take too much time to then dcast it back to the initial DT1. I appreciate your answer tough. For comparison 18 sec of system utilisation agaisnt 4 for the proposed answer.

Comment: In your actual data, how many "A" columns do you have?  In your example you have two "A1" and "A2"..

Comment: In the actual data, I have only two A but many M and many IND.

Comment: The dcast approach is still much faster than the loop solutions. I've provided an updated option